# Is the structure of "fraught by villainous scoundrels" acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, passive-voice, prepositional-phrases, past-participles

I'm writing a poem in which certain stanzas are of the form -

> The skill has been **taught** extensively
>
> It has been **taught** by aces;
>
> The journey is **fraught** with perils
>
> It (is/will be) **fraught** by villainous scoundrels  <--- This is the line I want to check.

Is the sentence structure of the last line valid?

The reason for using *fraught* in this way is that I wish to induce a certain poetic structure "X was *ught with Y; It was *ught with Z". I mean to express the idea "The journey is fraught with perils, which are placed by villainous scoundrels" but adhering to the above structure. Can "**fraught by...**" be used—and if so, is this the correct way to use it?

Comment: Have you looked up *fraught* in a dictionary? Do you find a contemporary use of *fraught* as past participle of a verb?

Comment: @StoneyB: Yup, wiktionary (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fraught) mentions fraught as an acceptable form of verb but it just does not read right to me...

Comment: *By* designates the agent of a passive; *freight/fraught* calls for a *with* PP designating the freight which is loaded onto the object; so what would you understand those villainous scoundrels to be loading onto the journey?

Comment: @StoneyB: Words before "by" don't always have to be the passive participle of currently used verbs. They do usually they have the *form* of a participle, but "fraught" seems to satisfy this criterion. Consider "beloved by" ("belove" is no longer used in the active voice), or "unwanted by" (which has no directly corresponding verb "to unwant"). Although "frought by" is much less common than "frought with", there seem to be a number of examples on Google Books: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fraught%20by%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @sumelic Granted: but in both cases *by* designates an Agent of *love* or *want*. My point is that both the obsolete verb and the modern adjective *fraught* select *with*, not *by* to designate the burden--which is why *by* "does not read right to" OP. As for a couple hundred uses on GB--this use seems to me comparable to the use by people of *ilk* to mean *sort* and *reticent* to mean *reluctant*--both are spreading, and both mark the user as an aspirant to educated usage, not an educated user. ... While you're at it, run *is fraught with* and *is fraught by* through Google NGrams!

Comment: Could you explain the meaning you want it to have? Why do you use "fraught with" in the previous line, and then "fraught by"? Do you mean to express something like "The journey is fraught with perils, which are **placed by** villainous scoundrels?" Or do you mean "The journey is fraught with perils, and fraught with villainous scoundrels"?

Comment: @sumelic: The reason for using fraught is that I wish to induce a certain poetic structure  "X was *ught with Y; It was *ught with Z"...I mean to express the first one - "The journey is fraught with perils, which are placed by villainous scoundrels" but adhering to the above structure...Let me know if it is not clear...